# Leaflet add Marker after loading the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

How is it possible to add an additional marker after the map is already loaded?

I tried to add a marker with a button:

```
L.easyButton('fa-compass', 
          function (){
            var newMarker = new L.marker(47.972850,7.856000).addTo(map); 
            map.update()},
         'Interact with the map'
        ).addTo(map)
```

The new marker doesn't show up. How is it possible to add the marker to the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use L.marker for this here place is a object of lat and long and map is your map holder

```
 L.marker(place, {
            draggable: true,
            title: "my point",
            alt: "my point",
            riseOnHover: true
        }).addTo(map)
```

See this http://jsfiddle.net/LnzN2/582/ for demo